# Why overflow setting of the html element is more important than the body element?

Tags: html, css

When the width of body or html is longer than the screen.The overflow setting of body can not overwrite the overflow setting of html.

I am trying to make an iframe to show some web page demos like jsfiddle's embed script.

And in my project assumption, I need the size of the iframe element to be fixed but there will be a toggle(4 buttons width[+][-] length[+][-]) to resize "virtual screen" of the demo page inside the iframe. Like that:

[image: My Aiming]

And with my test, I found that the only way to make it is inject some codes to the inside demo page whose function is "open/close overflow-x overflow-y and give it an min-width and min-height".

I don't want my code injection disturb(even impact) the normal functions of the demo page.

But the testing fact wasn't like my wish, When I inject an `html{overflow:scroll}` to the inside page and it has a original style like `body{overflow: hidde;width: 30000px;}` , the scrollbar still showed.

I don't know why body's setting did not overwrite the html's. And is there an another method to my aiming?

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hello world</div>
```

```css
html{
    overflow: scroll;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30000px;
}
```

result:
 [image: result]

Comment: Note that you have a typo in `body{ overflow: hidde; [...]`. Also, is there a reason you can't set the overflow property of the iframe (or the child thereof where the embed is contained), instead of injecting it into the embedded code?

Comment: Yeah overflow property of the iframe doesn't work in chrome. But only the `scrolling` attr of iframe tag works (`auto`, `no`(it has the most important priority even there is a `html{overflow:scroll;}` setting in the inside page)). And it can not control the single direction of overflow.

Comment: How about adding a container element like `<div>` inside the iframe and controlling that one (for example with `iframe > div { overflow-x: scroll; ... }`)?